# What is use of exclamation mark(!) in this qbasic programming?

Tags: qbasic

```
DECLARE SUB cube(!)
INPUT "Enter  a length";l
CALL cube(l)
END
SUB cube(l)
area=6*l^2
PRINT "Area of a cube",area
END SUB
```

Comment: I think it's a typographical error; none of QB 4.5, PDS 7.1, or QB64 will run the code. If it was something like `DECLARE SUB cube(value!)`, that would run.

Comment: qbasic successfully run the above code but what i didnot understand is the use of exclamation sign (!)

Comment: The `!` is used as a suffix on variables to tell QB that they are `SINGLE` variables.

Answer (score 2):

This snip describes calling a subroutine in QBasic to get the area of a cube:

```
DECLARE SUB Cube(L!)
INPUT "Enter a length"; L!
CALL Cube(L!)
END

SUB Cube (L!)
Area! = 6 * L! ^ 2
PRINT "Area of a cube"; Area!
END SUB
```

The ! declares a variable as single precision.